# Как загрузить песни из специальной папки на SD-карте ?(MediaStore.Audio.Media)

Tags: java, android

На sd карточке есть папка в которую будут загружаться из вне mp3 файлы.
Пытаюсь загрузить из папки музыку через этот код:

```
 private void loadAudio() {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[] { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA }, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA
                + " LIKE ' /storage/sdcard/Swirls/%'", null, "LOWER("
                + MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + ") ASC");

        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                //String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
                String data =  cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA ));
                String title =
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));
                String album =
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));
                String artist =
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));

                // Save to audioList
                audioList.add(new Audio(data, title, album, artist));
            }
        }
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
```

но `cursor.getCount()` постоянно равно 0.
В папке mp3 файлы есть.
Путь к папке на карте:

```
/storage/sdcard/Swirls/
```

разрешения все предоставлены и в манифесте прописаны.

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос так:

```
cursor = contentResolver.query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " like ? ",
            new String[] {"%Swirls%"},  null);
```